# Text file failing conversion at subscriber end

Tags: python, mqtt, publish-subscribe, mosquitto

I am trying to publish a text file. The format is .txt.

The text file is as follows

```
273    !Temperature
33     !Pressure
43     !Wind pressure
```

The code on publish side is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mosquitto

client = mosquitto.Mosquitto("txt-send")
client.connect("127.0.0.1")

f = open("data.txt")
imagestring = f.read()
byteArray = bytes(imagestring)
client.publish("text", byteArray ,0)
```

The code on subscriber side is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import mosquitto

def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
  with open('received.txt', 'wb') as fd:
    fd.write(msg.payload)
  #I have also tried the following
  #txt = (msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
  #fd.write(txt)



client = mosquitto.Mosquitto("text-rec")
client.connect("127.0.0.1")
client.subscribe("text",0)
client.on_message = on_message

while True:
   client.loop(15)
   time.sleep(2)
```

I get the following output in file

```
"273/t/t!Temperature/n33/t/t!Pressure/n43/t/t!Wind pressure"
```

Can someone suggest where am I going wrong.

Comment: When reading you don't get the newline characters, and when writing you don't add them yourself.

Comment: You may wish to unescape on the client side

Comment: @PaulStelian I do not add them myself. They are actually written in that format from some other code.

Comment: @PaulStelian Thanks a lot. I tried msg.payload.decode('string_escape') and that worked on subscriber side. Thank you.